# Nested class definition in concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins, activesupport-concern

I have pundit policy class which declares another class inside:

```
class PaymentPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      return scope.all if user.root?
      scope.where(user: user)
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to use this same inner `Scope` class in another place. One way is to define it in superclass and override, but to do that I have to create another class `class NewClass < ApplicationPolicy` and inherit `PaymentPolicy` from it.
But I like `ActiveSupport::Concern` and don't know how to put a class definition inside concern module.
This

```
module UserAllowed
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    class Scope < Scope
      def resolve
        return scope.all if user.root?
        scope.where(user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

doesn't work. Neither this:

```
   module UserAllowed
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      class Scope < Scope
        def resolve
          return scope.all if user.root?
          scope.where(user: user
        end
      end
    end
```

How can I put nested class definition inside concern module?

Comment: I'm confused by this: `class Scope < Scope`.  Also "doesn't work" is not helpful.  Tell us the error message.

Comment: Perhaps you should rename `Scope` to `BaseScope` to not blow the minds of those who maintain that code. Especially if that's you.

Comment: This `Scope < Scope` is how pundit works https://github.com/elabs/pundit. I also don't like it, but it's just the way it is.